# Coq seemingly refuses to recognize a simple substitution of a propositional formula for a propositional variable?

Tags: coq, substitution, coq-tactic

After many failures I discovered a strange thing Coq does that I don't understand.
Sorry for involved code, I was not able to isolate a simpler example.
I have a formula I call `trident` in three variables `p`, `q`, `r`.
I then simply write out an instance of this formula with `a <-> b` in place of `p`, `a` in place of `q` and `b` in place of `r`, and just try to prove a lemma stating that the result is equivalent to the substitution into `trident` as above. When trying to prove I am stuck with the first subgoal which reads

```
 a, b : Prop
  H : b
  ============================
  a \/ (a <-> b)
```

and this is obviously unprovable: if `b` is assumed to be true, then `a \/ (a <-> b)` becomes just `a`, and there is no reason for it to be true.

Here is the whole code:

```
From Coq Require Import Setoid.

Definition denseover (p q : Prop) := (p -> q) -> q.

Definition trident (p q r : Prop) :=
  (
       (denseover p (q \/ r)) 
    /\ (denseover q (r \/ p))
    /\ (denseover r (p \/ q))
  ) -> (p \/ q \/ r).

Lemma triexpand : forall a b : Prop,
     ((a <-> b) \/ a \/ b)
<-> ((a \/ (a -> b)) /\ (b \/ (b -> a))).

Proof.
tauto.
Qed.

Lemma substritwo : forall a b : Prop,
   (trident (a <-> b) a b)
<->
   (
    (
         (denseover (a <-> b) (a \/ b)) 
      /\ (denseover a (b \/ (a <-> b)))
      /\ (denseover b (a \/ (a <-> b)))
    ) -> ((a <-> b) \/ a \/ b)
   ).

Proof.
  unfold trident, denseover.
  split.
  rewrite triexpand.
  split.
  destruct H.
  destruct H0.
  destruct H.
  destruct H0.
  destruct H.
  destruct H0.
  intuition.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> a lemma stating that the result is equivalent to the substitution into trident as above

This should be trivial for Coq with a tactic such as `easy`. The fact that it doesn't work led me to discover that your lemma switched the order of a disjunction: the third statement with `denseover` is

```
denseover r (p \/ q)
```

in the definition of `trident` and

```
denseover b (a \/ (a <-> b))
```

in the lemma, instead of `denseover b ((a <-> b) \/ a)`.

If you change this, `easy` works.

But suppose you want to prove the lemma as stated. Then the argument is that `\/` is commutative, and you shouldn't be breaking down the statement, you should just rewrite with the commutativity lemma, which is called `or_comm`. Interestingly, the following doesn't work:

```
Proof.
  intros a b.
  rewrite (or_comm a (a <-> b)).
```

and it gives a scary-looking error. Here's why it shouldn't work: as of the current goal, `denseover` could be anything, and we don't know a priori that replacing arguments of `denseover` by equivalent (but not equal!) arguments will give the same result. As far as Coq knows without inspecting the definition of `denseover`, it could match on disjunctions and behave differently in the left and right branches.

In this case the problem is solved by simply unfolding `denseover`. Since this is a simple chain of implications, Coq knows that rewriting with equivalent statements is fine:

```
Proof.
  intros a b.
  unfold trident, denseover.
  now rewrite (or_comm a (a <-> b)).
Qed.
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I already accepted it but still, may I ask - how did I manage to hit an unprovable statement? Can one say that "if disjunction would be noncommutative" this would imply it?

Comment: You hit an unprovable statement because you destructed too much. Not every tactic preserves provability, sometimes they loose information.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Actually right now I was studying [a reply](https://coq.discourse.group/t/failing-to-prove-that-substituting-by-hand-is-equivalent-to-well-substituting/1491) at coq discourse with this kind of explanation. I certainly had no idea about what am I doing when doing `destruct`...